Setting of MainPage equivalent after deprecation
I have a Xamarin Forms app that I am updating to use Maui 9. In my app, there are a couple of places where I need to change the top-level page. I was able to do this by setting the MainPage property of the app.
The release notes for Maui 9 say to override CreateWindow to set MainPage at the start of the app, and use Application.Current.Windows[0].Page to get the page, but I can see no other way of setting MainPage... can anyone suggest how I can achieve the equivalent of setting MainPage (other than overriding CreateWindow)?

This question is similar to: .NET MAUI Application class MainPage is Obsolete. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the comment @BhavaneshN - the other question was asking how to access the MainPage, but I want to be able to set it in my app, and not necessarily at the start of the app in CreateWindow. I've updated the title of the question to be a bit more specific by mentioning "setting" and updated body to say other than CreateWindow.


Code that accesses the Application.Current.MainPage property should now access the Application.Current.Windows[0].Page property for apps with a single window.

As mentioned in documentation here. If you want to set Mainpage in runtime.You can define something like this.
   Application.Current.Windows[0].Page = new NewMainPage();


Thanks, yes that will do it, although care must be taken because depending on when this is called, the Windows collection may be empty. I've had to refactor so instead of setting MainPage, I call a function that will set Application.Current.Windows[0].Page if the Windows collection contains anything - if not I store the page, and then use it in the override of CreateWindow.
